# Google translate service for GNU gettext PO files that supports ngettext style plurals

Tags: translation, gettext, google-translate, poedit

I'm looking for a front-end to google translate that supports translating GNU gettext PO files with NGETEXT style plurals, eg. msgid_plural, msgid[0] ... msgid[n].

I've found several free translation services for PO files [1], but none of these services support ngettext style plural strings. Our PO files have a fair number of plurals that need to be converted.

Note: We recognize the google translations are not anywhere near production quality. We're using the translated PO files for testing/proof-of-concept demos only.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Malcolm

[1] Free, hosted PO translation services

- http://pepipopum.dixo.net/
- http://senko.net/services/googtext/

Comment: I would be happy to add support for plurals to my [cloud-translate tool](https://crates.io/crates/cloud-translate). See https://github.com/mgeisler/cloud-translate/issues/9.

Answer (score 2):

You could try Zanata (http://zanata.org) which is an open source web based translation service with full support of Gettext files (including pluralisation).

Answer (score 1):

There is also the http://littlesvr.ca/ostd/ translation service that uses po files translated for other open source projects to select the translations in 175 different languages. You can choose which translation to go for if there are differing translations.

Answer (score 0):

Try Transifex:
http://www.transifex.com

We use it extensively for translation of our website using gettext / PO files.